# Set properties for multiple headings

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to set the same property for multiple headings in one shot?

```
* Heading 1...
* Heading 2...
* Heading 3...
```

I would like to select all three headings and do <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to set a common property for these entries.

```
* Heading 1
      :PROPERTIES:
      :Source:   some common value
      :END:


* Heading 2
      :PROPERTIES:
      :Source:   some common value
      :END:


* Heading 3
      :PROPERTIES:
      :Source:   some common value
      :END:
```

Is it possible to set properties across headings without going through them one by one?

Comment: I recommend to use a keyboard macro.  E.g. C-x ( C-s Heading RET C-c C-x p Source RET some common value RET C-x ) C-x e e e...

Comment: You may be able to use [property inheritance](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Inheritance.html#Property-Inheritance) instead?